# IOS notifications worked in Xcode testing in release mode but aren't working now that I have released the app to appstore

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a flutter app that uses firebase messaging to send the admin a notification every time a booking is made, I  have testing this both on android and on iOS release mode and it worked perfectly so I released the app and now it isn't working anymore, I have send a firebase cloud message to the user to test the fcm token and it was received perfectly. What could be the reason for it working successfully in the simulator and in release mode on a real device but then not work once released?

Comment: Have you triend putting apns key on the firebase on ios? Also created a certificate for push notification in appstore? Already done that?

Comment: yes I have done all steps and it worked testing on a real device in release mode